# Sharing connection pools between client instances in finagle

Tags: finagle

Given two or more finagle clients that have different destination names, if those names happen to resolve to the same inet address how to I get finagle to only maintain a single pool of connections to that endpoint?

**Overly Simple Sample Code**

The below code registers a very simple (and mostly useless) [Resolver](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/docs/com/twitter/finagle/Resolver.html) that always resolves to the same address. In practice this would be more like a many to one relationship (instead of all to one). There's another simple application that starts a server and two clients that both use the resolver to find the address to talk to the server.

```java
// Registered with finagle Resolver via META-INF/services
class SmartResolver extends AbstractResolver {
  @Override public String scheme() { return "smart"; }
  @Override public Var<Addr> bind(String arg) {
    return Vars.newConstVar(Addrs.newBoundAddr(Addresses.newInetAddress(
        // assume this is more complicated and maps many names to 
        //  one address
        new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9000)))));
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a server, we record stats so we can see how many connections
    // there are
    InMemoryStatsReceiver stats = new InMemoryStatsReceiver();
    ListeningServer server = Thrift.server()
        .withStatsReceiver(stats)
        .serveIface(":9000", (EchoService.ServiceIface) Future::value);

    // create a few clients that all connect to a resolved server, the
    // resolver ensures that they all are communicating with our server
    EchoService.ServiceIface c1 = Thrift.client()
        .newIface("smart!c1", EchoService.ServiceIface.class);
    EchoService.ServiceIface c2 = Thrift.client()
        .newIface("smart!c2", EchoService.ServiceIface.class);

    // make sure any lazy connections have been opened
    Await.result(c1.echo("c1"));
    Await.result(c2.echo("c2"));

    // I'm not sure how to see how many physical connections there are 
    // incoming to the server, or if it's possible to do this.
    assertEquals(1, stats.counter(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("connects"))))

    Await.result(server.close());
  }
}
```

```
// echo.thrift
service EchoService {
  string echo(1: string quack);
}
```

**All the details**

Where I work we have a microservice architecture using finagle and thrift, we use Consul for service discovery. Some of the external systems we interact with are very restrictive about the number and frequency of tcp connections they accept, for this reason some service instances are 'assigned responsibility' for these connections. To make sure that requests that need to use specific connections are sent to the correct service, that service registers a new service name in consul representing the connection it is responsible for. Clients then lookup the service by the connection name instead of the service name.

To make that clearer: Say you have a `device-service` that opens TCP connections to a configured list of devices, the devices only support a single connection at a time. You might have a few instances of this `device-service` with some scheme in place to divide the devices between the `device-service` instances. So instance `A` connects to devices `foo` and `bar`, instance `B` connects to `baz`.

You now have another service, say `poke-service` that needs to talk to specific devices (via the `device-service`). The way I've solved this issue is to have the `device-service` instance `A` register `foo` and `bar`, and instance `B` register `baz`, all against their own local address. So looking up `foo` resolves to the address for `device-service` instance `A` instead of the more generic cluster of all `device-service` instances.

The problem I'd like to solve is an optimisation problem, I'd like finagle to recognise that both `foo` and `bar` actually resolve to the same address and to reuse all the resources that it allocates and maintains as part of the connection. Additionally if `foo` and `bar` get re-assigned to different `device-service` instances, I'd like everything to *just work* based on the information in Consul which would reflect this change.

Comment: Hi Matt, I was wondering if you have found a solution for this already as I have the same exact use case and question!

Comment: Sorry @Jim, I haven't found a solution for this outside managing the finagle client instances manually and effectively bypassing the resolver layer.